# SimpleFacets.lamba and NumberFormatException Errors on Enum FieldType in Solr

Tags: solr, enums

Has anyone ever tried sorting on a enum field? I've got a field defined as an enum with a custom enumConfig.xml file that has about 1000 different values. If I try to make a range query on this enum field or sort by it, I get this exception:

```
Invalid shift value in prefixCoded bytes (is encoded value really an INT?).
```

The values in the config file have both numbers and characters in them, if it's relevant/important...

It gives me a nasty exception if I try to facet on the field, too:

```
"msg": "Exception during facet.field: ORBIT",
"trace": "org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Exception during
facet.field: ORBIT\n\tat org.apache.solr.request.SimpleFacets.lambda$getFacetFieldCounts$0(SimpleFacets.java:766)
```

Says it's a NumberFormatException ...?

Although I only get that exception if I specify "facet.limit=-1", it works for small values.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out weird errors like that can occur if you make changes to the enum config file, even if you reindex. I had to completely delete my collection to get it to work.